# Tool to sync keyboard shortcuts for programming IDE's

Tags: software-development, ide, programming, keyboard-shortcuts

As a developer I use multiple IDE's like Visual Studio, VS Code, Sublime, intelliJ, Android studio, ect. Almost all of them have a way to customize and store shortcut/keymap settings. I use this  a lot because almost all IDE's have a different default and I have my personal preferences.

Is there a tool or way to store and synchronize keymaps and/or settings for IDE's? When using multiple IDE's on different computers it's going to take a lot of time configuring.

Jetbrain IDE's have setting repositories, which is great, but limited to the Jetbrains environments only.

If this doesn't exist; are more people interested in this?

Comment: I guess it depends on precisely which IDEs. I find debuggers are worst for this ... grrrrr

Comment: there's https://editorconfig.org/ for settings, I wonder if it could be extended for keyboard shortcuts as well. but different software can have very different approaches to this, just think random conventional IDE vs vim's modal editing